# pythonic way to index list of objects

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I have a list of objects. Each object has two fields

```
obj1.status = 2
obj1.timestamp = 19211

obj2.status = 3
obj2.timestamp = 14211

obj_list = [obj1, obj2]
```

I will keep adding / deleting objects in the list and also changing attributes of objects, for example I may change ob1.status to 5.
Now I have two dicts

```
dict1 - <status, object>
dict2 - <timestamp, object>
```

How do I design a simple solution so that whenever I modify/delete/insert elements in the list, the maps get automatically updated. I am interested in a pythonic solution that is elegant and extensible. For example in future, I should be able to easily add another attribute and dict for that as well

Also for simplicity, let us assume all attributes value are different. For example no two objects will have same status

Comment: Why would you create dictionaries of `<status, object>` and `<timestamp, object>` when the object already has both the attributes?

Comment: I want indexes for fast access  , for example I want to get object of status 3

Comment: What happens if multiple objects have similar status or timestamp?

Comment: we can modify the map to be <status, set(object)> ... for simplicity , let us assume all attributes are different

Comment: There is no general solution for this; if your objects are mutable then you end up with an `O(n)` lookup to find the one you're after. You get the benefits of a dictionary when their keys are stable.

Comment: Is it okay if the list is not a builtin list but a collection which returns proxies which can get and set attributes on the real objects while maintaining state on the source collection?

Comment: Also please demonstrate some effort; where is the [mcve] of your current implementation and its problems?

Comment: @jonrsharpe  Generalising to O(n) is not really accurate, it depends on the data.  Consider for example some tree structures with O(log n) lookups.

Comment: @wim fair point, but that's still a way short of `O(1)`!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want 0(1) lookup on selected attributes. Consider this like an in memory RDBMS, where we only need fast lookup on attributes (no other queries)

Comment: Ok, so *what have you got*? Is this a profiled bottleneck or a premature optimisation?

Comment: @darkknight There is not really enough useful information in your question to give a meaningful answer yet.  How frequent are writes relative to reads?  If changes are seldom, is a post-save signal on write to update the mappings feasible?

Comment: @win we don't want wrong/stale lookups happening. Let us say read/write are same frequency.  I want to know what is a good python design so that mappings are easily updated with less code, without writing lot of corner cases and solution is extensible as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override the `__setattr__` on the objects to update the indexes whenever you set the values.  You can use a `weakref` dictionary for the indexes so that when you delete objects and are no longer using them, they are automatically removed from the indexes.

```
import weakref
from bunch import Bunch


class MyObject(object):

    indexes = Bunch()  # Could just use dict()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyObject, self).__init__()
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        try:
            index = MyObject.indexes[name]
        except KeyError:
            index = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()
            MyObject.indexes[name] = index
        try:
            old_val = getattr(self, name)
            del index[old_val]
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            pass
        object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
        index[value] = self


obj1 = MyObject(status=1, timestamp=123123)
obj2 = MyObject(status=2, timestamp=2343)


print MyObject.indexes.status[1]
print obj1.indexes.timestamp[2343]
obj1.status = 5
print obj2.indexes['status'][5]
```

I used a `Bunch` here because it allows you to access the indexes using `.name` notation, but you could just use a `dict` instead and use the `['name']` syntax.

Comment: Nice! Deletion is not working.  The element is only deleted from the list , so a strong reference to object is still in memory. Also would be nice to generalize this so that instead of creating status_map and timestamp_map, the class could take as input list of attributes and build from there.

Comment: You'd have to delete all the references.  That means deleting it from the list and doing `del obj1`.  Also, if you're doing this from python prompt, the last returned value gets set to the `_` variable, so you'll need to reset that or delete it as well.

Comment: @darkknight Yeah, you could do Yakym did and just make them class attributes, so that you don't have to create them outside of the class.

Comment: Thought again ... deleting object also does makes sense. Deletion is working.

Comment: again don't want to create property for each attribute. So thinking if we can further create a fixed code that would work for any number of attributes

Comment: @darkknight  Updated the answer to be a more general solution.  I stored the indexes as class attributes like in [Yakym's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37489536/1547004).  The only requirement is that you instantiate the objects using keyword arguments for the attributes.

Comment: @darkknight Are all the attributes going to be unique per object?  Or should the indexes be store *sets* of objects that all share that same value?  As in, multiple objects could have a status of `1`, so the indexed entry for `1` would contain a `set()` of all multiple objects, all with status `1`.

Comment: Awesome solution. Yes attributes will be unique per object, I updated the question reflecting that. We can easily extend your solution to the case there values are set()

Answer (score 2):

One approach here would be to create a class level `dict` for `MyObj` and define updating behavior using `property` decorator. Every time an object is changed or added, it is reflected in the respected dictionaries associated with the class.

Edit: as @BrendanAbel points out, using `weakref.WeakValueDictionary` in place of `dict` handles object deletion from class level dicts.

```
from datetime import datetime
from weakref import WeakValueDictionary

DEFAULT_TIME = datetime.now()


class MyObj(object):
    """
    A sample clone of your object
    """
    timestamps = WeakValueDictionary()
    statuses   = WeakValueDictionary()

    def __init__(self, status=0, timestamp=DEFAULT_TIME):
        self._status    = status
        self._timestamp = timestamp

        self.status     = status
        self.timestamp  = timestamp

    def __update_class(self):
        MyObj.timestamps.update({self.timestamp: self})
        MyObj.statuses.update({self.status: self})

    def __delete_from_class(self):
        maybe_self = MyObj.statuses.get(self.status, None)
        if maybe_self is self is not None:
            del MyObj.statuses[self.status]

        maybe_self = MyObj.timestamps.get(self.timestamp, None)
        if maybe_self is self is not None:
            del MyObj.timestamps[self.timestamp]

    @property
    def status(self):
        return self._status

    @status.setter
    def status(self, val):
        self.__delete_from_class()
        self._status = val
        self.__update_class()

    @property
    def timestamp(self):
        return self._timestamp

    @timestamp.setter
    def timestamp(self, val):
        self.__delete_from_class()
        self._timestamp = val
        self.__update_class()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "MyObj: status={} timestamp={}".format(self.status, self.timestamp)


obj1 = MyObj(1)
obj2 = MyObj(2)
obj3 = MyObj(3)

lst = [obj1, obj2, obj3]

# In [87]: q.lst
# Out[87]: 
# [MyObj: status=1 timestamp=2016-05-27 13:43:38.158363,
#  MyObj: status=2 timestamp=2016-05-27 13:43:38.158363,
#  MyObj: status=3 timestamp=2016-05-27 13:43:38.158363]

# In [88]: q.MyObj.statuses[1]
# Out[88]: MyObj: status=1 timestamp=2016-05-27 13:43:38.158363

# In [89]: q.MyObj.statuses[1].status = 42

# In [90]: q.MyObj.statuses[42]
# Out[90]: MyObj: status=42 timestamp=2016-05-27 13:43:38.158363

# In [91]: q.MyObj.statuses[1]
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-91-508ab072bfc4> in <module>()
# ----> 1 q.MyObj.statuses[1]

# KeyError: 1
```

Comment: @darkknight good edit, although it is not required for python 3.

Comment: Nice ! Doesn't work when item is deleted from list. Also added an assumption in question. So maybe  __delete_from_class can be removed.

Comment: You are correct, this does not update the dicts when an object is removed from the list. The __delete_from_class is used to make sure that the same object is not pointed to by two different values.

Comment: If you make the indexes `weakref.WeakValueDictionary`'s, it will automatically remove them when you delete the object

Answer (score 1):

For a collection to be aware of mutation of its elements, there must be some connection between the elements and that collection which can communicate when changes happen. For this reason, we either must bind an instance to a collection or proxy the elements of the collection so that change-communication doesn't leak into the element's code.

A note about the implementation I'm going to present, the proxying method only works if the attributes are changed by direct setting, not inside of a method. A more complex book-keeping system would be necessary then.

Additionally, it assumes that exact duplicates of all attributes won't exist, given that you require the indices be built out of `set` objects instead of `list`

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Proxy(object):
    def __init__(self, proxy, collection):
        self._proxy = proxy
        self._collection = collection

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name in ("_proxy", "_collection"):
           return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        else:
           proxy = self._proxy
           return getattr(proxy, name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name in ("_proxy", "collection"):
           object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
        else:
           proxied = self._proxy
           collection = self._collection
           old = getattr(proxied, name)
           setattr(proxy, name, value)
           collection.signal_change(proxied, name, old, value)


class IndexedCollection(object):
     def __init__(self, items, index_names):
         self.items = list(items)
         self.index_names = set(index_names)
         self.indices = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set))

     def __len__(self):
         return len(self.items)

     def __iter__(self):
         for i in range(len(self)):
             yield self[i]    

     def remove(self, obj):
         self.items.remove(obj)
         self._remove_from_indices(obj)

     def __getitem__(self, i):
         # Ensure consumers get a proxy, not a raw object
         return Proxy(self.items[i], self)

     def append(self, obj):
         self.items.append(obj)
         self._add_to_indices(obj)

     def _add_to_indices(self, obj):
          for indx in self.index_names:
              key = getattr(obj, indx)
              self.indices[indx][key].add(obj)

     def _remove_from_indices(self, obj):
          for indx in self.index_names:
              key = getattr(obj, indx)
              self.indices[indx][key].remove(obj)

     def signal_change(self, obj, indx, old, new):
          if indx not in self.index_names:
               return
          # Tell the container to update its indices for a
          # particular attribute and object
          self.indices[indx][old].remove(obj)
          self.indices[indx][new].add(obj)
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is what you are asking for but ...

Objects:

```
import operator
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.one = 1
        self.two = 2

f = Foo()
f.name = 'f'
g = Foo()
g.name = 'g'
h = Foo()
h.name = 'h'

name = operator.attrgetter('name')
```

lists: `a` initially contains `f` and `b` initially contains `h`

```
a = [f]
b = [h]
```

dictionaries: each with one item *whose* value is one of the lists

```
d1 = {1:a}
d2 = {1:b}
```

`d1[1]` is list `a` which contains `f` and `f.one` is 1

```
>>> d1
{1: [<__main__.Foo object at 0x03F4CA50>]}
>>> name(d1[1][0])
'f'
>>> name(d1[1][0]), d1[1][0].one
('f', 1)
```

changing `f.one` is *seen* in the dictionary

```
>>> f.one = '?'
>>> name(d1[1][0]), d1[1][0].one
('f', '?')
>>>
```

`d2[1]` is list `b` which contains `h`

```
>>> d2
{1: [<__main__.Foo object at 0x03F59070>]}
>>> name(d2[1][0]), d2[1][0].one
('h', 1)
```

Add an object to `b` and it is *seen* in the dictionary

```
>>> b.append(g)
>>> b
[<__main__.Foo object at 0x03F59070>, <__main__.Foo object at 0x03F4CAF0>]
>>> d2
{1: [<__main__.Foo object at 0x03F59070>, <__main__.Foo object at 0x03F4CAF0>]}
>>> name(d2[1][1]), d2[1][1].one
('g', 1)
```